# What is "let [a,,b] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" with two commas (,,) doing and how can it be used?

Tags: javascript

I came upon this piece of code `let [a,,b] = [1, 2, 3];` javascript at the babel compiler website and it has made me curious. What is it doing exactly? How and where can I use it in a useful way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It names: Destructuring.
It is super useful for handling objects ands arrays.

I will try to give you a real example usage:

Imagine you are working with a form, where you have to pass some fileds of information through it, and save it in your database.

```
//Form:

Name: Donald
City: USA
Age: 45
```

You will need to pass this data, in some object called 'formData':

```
const formData = {name:'donald', city:'USA',age:45}
```

If you need to handle each object's element, you will have to write everytime:

```
console.log(formData.name) // => donald
console.log(formData.city) // => USA
console.log(formData.age) // => 45
```

With destructuring, you can rename this elements in variables:

```
const {name, city, age} = formData
```

You are assigning for each formData element a constant variable, easier to write and read it:

```
console.log(name) // => Donald
console.log(city) // => USA
console.log(age)  // => 45
```

In your case, element between commas, it will be skkiped:

```
const array = [1,2,3]

const a,,c} = array;
console.log(a) // => 1
// b position will be skipped
console.log(c) // => 3
```

There is another feature part of destructuring: [rest pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable) (as @VLAZ said)

```
const rainbow = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
const [red,, yellow, ...otherColors] = rainbow;
console.log(otherColors); // ['green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']
```

Check more examples and possible cases:

[clickHere](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f)

Comment: I don't think destructuring is in any way related to OOP.

Comment: "*With destructuring, you can rename this elements in variables:*" you can also do this *without* a destructuring assignment. The only thing destructuring gives you is it makes it slightly shorter. `const {a,,c} = formData` this statement makes no sense - when doing *object* destructuring, the values won't be taken "in order" but explicitly by name. So skipping is a meaningless operation.

Comment: "*There is another feature linked with destructuring: spread operator*" no, the spread syntax is completely unrelated to destructuring. You're referring to the [rest pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable) which *is* part of destructuring.

Comment: you are absolutely right in your two last comments, sorry for that, I am going to edit them. However, I said 
"It is super useful in OOP (Object-oriented programming)" 
don't you agree with this?

Comment: Destructuring is simply not related to OOP. It's just a convenient way to declare variables that come from an object or from an array. It's syntactic sugar and can be used in functional programming as well as object-oriented programming among other styles. The four major principles in OOP are encapsulation, abstraction, polymorphism, and inheritance - destructuring has no bearing on any of those. Big OO languages like Java or C# have not introduced destructuring assignments, either, so were this OOP related you'd expect it would have been done or at least would have some traction.

Comment: under my short experience I felt It is useful and pragmatic to handle in OOP

I guess you are still right again

I will read more, thanks for sharing

Comment: It can be used with *objects* but that doesn't make it object *oriented*.

Answer (score 4):

```
let [a,,b] = [1, 2, 3]
```

This is part of something called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

The double comma denotes that a value (on the right side of the operation) should be skipped.

Ergo, `a` will have the value 1 and `b` will have 3. Nothing will be assigned the value 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is a concept known as *destructuring*, and you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). The code you are asking about simply obtains the first and last items of an array, ignoring the one in the middle. It is used when you just don't care about a specific position in an array so you don't bother saving it to a variable (see the **[Ignoring some returned values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values)** section in the link above).